# Can we write all the control events in a seperate class file in different layer rather than in code-behind of web-page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, layered

Can we write all the control events in a seperate class file in different layer rather than in code-behind of web-page ? Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is called [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc). With web-forms you could achieve what you want, but it won't be pretty.

Comment: We are trying to separate the UI layer with code-behind logic. UI layer would only have UI and client side validations, while all the logic would be there in seperate EventManager layer.

Comment: I tried to achieve it by partial classes but partial classes work only if they are in same namespace.

Comment: @HotTester ASP.Net MVC is designed to separate UI layer from "business logic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. One way of doing that is to make a partial class with the same name as your codebehind file and use that to contain the events.